# Apple Watch how to trigger a notification or glance from the main app

Tags: objective-c, apple-watch

I would like to trigger the Apple Watch notification and or the glance views from the main app.

I know how to run them in XCode and selecting those directly, but I need to make them popup from inside the main app programmatically.

In my main app I have a timer that today creates a popup to tell the user something. I would like that same trigger to show the notification view on the apple watch along with dynamic text. To keep it simple for now, suppose I have a button (IBAction). when the button is pressed in the main app I would like to show a glance or show the notification views on the watch.  I am guessing this is fairly simple to do but havent been able to make it work, yet.

If you have some sample code that would be great!

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What does this have to do with the `xcode IDE`? Why are you using that tag?

Comment: I am looking for an answer too. How to trigger a glance from within my iOS app?

Comment: I dont think its possible to trigger it. It sounds like so far Apple wants to trigger it when IOS wants to.   I hope they change this sometime.  Sounds like notification and glance are the same problem

Comment: Popeye I didnt use the Xcode tag???

Answer (score 0):

While iOS automatically shows notification controller when app receives remote or local notification.

But during development, you can trigger a notification or glance by changing **Watch Interface** in **WatchKit App Schema**. (**Edit Schema** -> (Under Info) Change **Watch Interface** to Glance/Static Notification / Dynamic Notification ).

However, Selecting Notification requires **Notification Payload** (create **.apns** file and set it to Notification Payload while editing schema) as well.

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I added some more to my original question. I would like this to work in production. While I know I can make both the glance and notify work in development I do need to make them dynamic from the main app side

Comment: How to trigger local notification in watch.